# jQuery - Loop through variable/elements?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load specific products into divs but each div is only loading in the first product.  I'm guessing I need to do a loop of some sort but I'm not quite sure how

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

```
<div class="prdContainer" rel="prod-1"></div>
<div class="prdContainer" rel="prod-2"></div>
<div class="prdContainer" rel="prod-3"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var prdNo = $('.prdContainer').attr('rel').split('-')[1];

    $('.prdContainer').load('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(' + prdNo + ')');
});
```

**In my mind this is what it SHOULD be doing:**

```
$('.prdContainer').load('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(1)');
$('.prdContainer').load('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(2)');
$('.prdContainer').load('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(3)');
```

**Which would be associated with:**

```
rel="prod-1"
rel="prod-2"
rel="prod-3"
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.prdContainer').each(function(i){
    $(this).load('http://www.domain.com .product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ')');
  });
});
```

you should know that index starts from 0

Comment: Thanks!!  This works great.  I was looking at it the wrong way it seems :)

Comment: @meskobalazs I tried to be faster but sometimes I can't do that .. My best Wishes to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the *attribute equals* selector (official [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)):

```
$('.prdContainer[rel="prod-' + prdNo + '"]').load(...);
```